# How to discover when Django emits COMMIT sql statements

Tags: django, relational-database, commit

I use Django and postgres. I need to examine Django SQL activity for optimization, but `connection.queries` doesn't include COMMIT statements. Does anybody know how I can find the way how transaction strategies I use in code exactly affect SQL commands? Ideally I want to have a list like  `connection.queries` but with commits and rollbacks included.

Comment: Have you consider just to tail the database log? There you can see all the activity that happens on you database.

Comment: Yes, but it's not a convenient way to see what happens with concrete transaction

Comment: @danihp These pages do not answer my question

Comment: I would use django debug toolbar to analyze the queries generated

Comment: @andrefsp thats not really practical unless you dont have anything else happening on your database.